# XOR type scenario in C outputs incorrectly

Tags: c, binary, compare, xor

Basically I am making a program that is evaluating CRC on an initial hex value. In this case:

```
Hex = AB1245
```

I have converted it to binary in the program:

```
1010 1011 0001 0010 0100 0101
```

This is CRC-8 with a given polynomial:

```
1 1111 1011
```

So far, I have used this information to create the following setup:

```
1010 1011 0001 0010 0100 0101 0000 0000
1111 1101 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Where those two strings should be XOR'd and a new string would be produced. It should be:

```
0101 0110 1001 0010 0100 0101 0000 0000
```

My code is as such:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(binary); i++) {
     if (binary[i] == polynomial[i])
         strcat(binary2, "0");
     else
         strcat(binary2, "1");
}
```

Where binary is

```
1010 1011 0001 0010 0100 0101
```

, polynomial is

```
1111 1101 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and `binary2` is the new binary string that should be created from them being XOR'd.

My problem is whenever I run this program, it is correct up to the last 4 bits, where it makes them all `1`s for no reason. So my output is:

```
0101 0110 1001 0010 0100 0101 0000 1111
```

The last four bits should be 0 until the polynomial string gets pushed over that far. I am totally out of ideas as to why this is happening. Can anyone shed some light?

---

**EDIT:** More code as requested.

`binary` is initiated as:

```
char binary[4*strlen(hex)];
```

where hex is the string of hexidecimal values `AB1245`

The next bit is the process used to both create polynomial and append the 0 bits to the end of `binary` (needed for CRC calculation):

```
char polynomial[10] = "111111011";

// Append the necessary number of bits to the binary string
int track = strlen(binary);
strcat(binary, "00000000"); //This is static as 8 zeroes are always used in CRC-8

// Create the polynomial w/ tail for the XOR steps
char tail[strlen(binary)];
strcpy(tail, "0"); //For some reason if I don't do this it freaks out

for (i=0; i < strlen(binary)-strlen(polynomial); i++)
       strcat(tail, "0");

strcat(polynomial, tail);
```

At this point I can verify they are the same length by printing the result of the `strlen()` on both of them. They both correctly come out to `32`.

Comment: `binary` is 3 bytes and your loop only goes up to the length of it, which is 24.  Your output string should only be 24 bits instead of 32.  Are you null terminating these strings?

Comment: Are the arrays binary and polynomial the same size?

Comment: It should be 32 for display purposes. I want 8 trailing 0's. The two strings being compared are the same length (32) and are null terminated as far as I know. I didn't know you could create strings in C using character arrays that weren't.

Comment: Your question indicates you know what XOR is but your code doesn't, leading me to believe maybe you didn't post the real code.

Comment: @user1067354 are you omitting the least significant byte in `binary`?

Comment: No, all bytes are counted because they all need to display. That and this is only the first step in a long process that will eventually get to the end of binary so I am trying to make it automated.

Comment: Don't forget that strings in C need a `'\0'` byte at the end; you should probably be allocating `char binary[4*strlen(hex)+1];`, and you also need to ensure strings are null terminated at all times, which is why the `strcpy(tail, "0");` improves things.

Comment: You're omitting it in the question where the trailing 0's are necessary.  "Where binary is

1010 1011 0001 0010 0100 0101"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're allocating your strings on the stack with lengths calculated from other strings allocated in a similar manner.  This presents two main problems:

First, char arrays will *not* automatically grow to fit whatever you put in them, and they must be sized to include a null terminated byte after the entire text.  So binary and polynomial should be declared as `char binary[33];` or even more than 33 depending on what other inputs are possible.  If you want them to "grow" then you will need to use `malloc` to dynamically allocate them.  **This is most likely the cause of your problems, you're overflowing at least one and probably several of your arrays.**

Second, char arrays must be initialized to be empty, they are not empty by default (they contain "garbage") and so taking their length or concatenating to them will produce unexpected results.